# TinyMCE custom button with font awesome 6 icon

Tags: font-awesome

I am trying to add a custom button to TinyMCE which has font awesome icon on it.

In the page header I am referencing my fa kit

```
  <script data-search-pseudo-elements src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/--------.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I am adding the button to TinyMCE

```
        editor.addButton('my_mediaButton', {
                text: '',
                icon: 'mediaButton',
                tooltip: 'Insert Picture from Media folder',
                onclick: function() {
                    OpenMedia();
                    return false;
                }
        });
```

I have added this to my css but it just renders as a little square

```
.mce-ico.mce-i-mediaButton:before {
    font: var(--fa-font-solid);
    content: "\f03e";
}
```

Inspecting the ::before element in Chrome, the variable is showing as

```
normal 900 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Solid"
```